# How can I use a narrowing conversion?

Tags: c++

```
bool digit{ (pdigit >= bdigitplace) ? 1 : 0 };
```

Both `pdigit` and `bdigitplace` are of type `int` and need to be. `digit` does not have to be boolean, but for the sake of aesthetics, I would like it to be.

The line returns error C2397 in Visual Studios: "conversion from 'int' to 'bool' requires a narrowing conversion"

How can I make this line work while still using a conditional operator and keeping `digit` type `bool`?

Comment: take out the text `? 1 : 0`

Comment: "still using a conditional operator"? well ok..  `bool digit{  ((1?2:3), pdigit >= bdigitplace) };`

Comment: Why do you want to keep using the conditional operator? Do you like your code to be harder to read than necessary? Use `bool digit{pdigit >= bdigitplace};` as MM suggests. Personally, I'd not even use list initialization in this case, instead write `bool digit = pdigit >= bdigitplace;`

Comment: Because the conditional operator isn't hard to read. However this `bool digit = pdigit >= bdigitplace;` did not occur to me and is quite nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use true and false instead of 1 and 0

Comment: You're a god. Any chance you could elaborate on why this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because narrowing conversion with the curly braces does not allow an int to be converted to a bool. Read this, it might help:

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
>
> — from a floating-point type to an integer type, or
>
> — from long double to
> double or float, or from double to float, except where the source is a
> constant expression and the actual value after conversion is within
> the range of values that can be represented (even if it cannot be
> represented exactly), or
>
> — from an integer type or unscoped
> enumeration type to a floating-point type, except where the source is
> a constant expression and the actual value after conversion will fit
> into the target type and will produce the original value when
> converted back to the original type, or
>
> — from an integer type or
> unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all
> the values of the original type, except where the source is a constant
> expression and the actual value after conversion will fit into the
> target type and will produce the original value when converted back to
> the original type. As indicated above, such conversions are not
> allowed at the top level in list-initializations

This can simply be fixed by using true or false instead of 1 and 0.